# Strict form of Hahn Banach inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $B$ be a Banach space. Let $x\in B.$ Then by Hahn-Banach there exists $f\in B^\ast$ such that $\|f\| =1$ and $f(x) = \|x\|.$

Question: can we strengthen this result so that now, for each $\epsilon>0$ we can find $f$ satisfying the following inequality: for all $y\in B$ such that $\|y\|=\|x\|,$ whenever $f(y)=\|x\|,$ we have $\|y-x\|<\epsilon$? This will simplify the proof of many results.

Edit: I just realised that strict convexity needs to be assumed.

Comment: You want $\|f\|=1$, not $\|f\|=\|x\|$.

Comment: In general, no, we cannot. Take $B=\ell_\infty^2$ and let $x=(1,0)$. There is a unique functional $f\in B^*$ with $\|f\|=1$ and $f(x)=\|x\|$, which is $f(a,b)=a$. But we can choose any $y=(1,t)$, $-1\leqslant t\leqslant 1$, and have $\|y\|=\|x\|$ and $f(y)=\|x\|$.

Comment: @user469053 Yes. $\|f\|=1.$

Comment: @user469053 I just realised that strict convexity needs to be assumed.

Comment: Even strict convexity is not enough. You can endow $\ell_\infty$ with a strictly convex norm, and it contains roughly the same type of examples.

Comment: Check the definition "uniformly convex space" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_space